# GoLang, запуск консольных команд

Tags: linux, golang

Необходимо запустить с помощью go консольную команду для linux

```
 mail -s "Thema" mgeorgim33@gmail.com < f1
```

Не могу разобраться как это сделать, делал так

```
cmd := exec.Command( "mail","-s",`"Thema" mgeorgim33@gmail.com < f1` )
cmd.Run()
```

f1 - файл с текстом сообщения

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/

Comment: Да, видел, но пока не могу разобраться что к чему

Comment: @Geo конкретно что не получается?

Comment: тут по сути 2 команды консольные и вот как их вызвать в exec.Command

Comment: [How to pipe several commands in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10781516)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

у вас f1 - это переменная, которая содержит путь до файла?  если да, то просто подставьте путь в args

```golang
import (
    "os/exec"
    "os"
    "syscall"
)

func main() {
    mail, lookErr := exec.LookPath("mail")
    if lookErr != nil {
        panic(lookErr)
    }

    args := []string{ "-v -s \"This is the subject\" my@mail.ru <<< 'This is the message'"}

    env := os.Environ()

    execErr := syscall.Exec(mail, args, env)
    if execErr != nil {
        panic(execErr)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так:

```golang
f, err := os.Open("f1")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer f.Close()

cmd := exec.Command("mail", "-s", "Subj", "user@example.com")
cmd.Stdin = f
cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
err = cmd.Run()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"<" - это параметр команды, а указание для bash (или другой оболочки) направить файл на стандартный вход команды.

Чтобы сделать то же самое в Go код будет примерно таким:

```
package main

import (
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    // Открыть файл, который надо направить на вход программы mail
    f, _ := os.Open("f")

    // Подготовить команду на запуск программы вместе с параметрами
    c := exec.Command("mail", "-s", "Thema", "mgeorgim33@gmail.com")

    // указываем, что в качестве стандартного входа будем использовать содержимое ранее открытого файла 
    c.Stdin = f

    // запустить команду
    c.Run()

    // закрыть файл
    f.Close()
}
```